# Was bedeutet „so viel wie“ in diesen Kontexten?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich bin dabei, [einen Text über ausgewanderte Wörter](http://www.zeit.de/2006/47/Trotz_noiroze_zur_arubaito_) zu lesen, und in diesem Text bin ich zweimal auf eine Verwendung von *so viel* getroffen, die ich nicht völlig verstehe.

> Das schönste Beispiel ist vielleicht der Begriff *nusu kaput* aus dem ostafrikanischen Kiswahili. In der Sprache bedeutet *nusu* **so viel wie** „halb“, *kaput* eben „kaputt“, und als Summe ergibt das: „Narkose“.

Und dann noch:

> Besonders erfolgreich waren und sind die Wörter aus dem Oktoberfest-Komplex. *Kipp es!* heißt auf Finnisch und in Argentinien **so viel wie** „Prost!“.

Die wörtliche Bedeutung scheint hier nicht so gut zu passen, also was bedeutet *so viel wie* in diesen Kontexten?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es bedeutet so viel wie

> das gleiche wie

Comment: See what you did there -.-

Answer (score 2):

**So viel wie** drückt einen Vergleich aus, der die beiden zu vergleichenden Dinge jedoch nicht eins zu eins gleichsetzt, sondern immer einen kleinen **Unterschied** impliziert. Übersetzungen sind ein gutes Beispiel, da der implizierte Unterschied hier z.B. der kulturelle Kontext ist. "Kipp es!" ist ein spezifischer Term aus dem Kontext des Oktoberfests, da es in Finnald jedoch kein Oktoberfest gibt, kann man "Kipp es!" mit dem finnischen "Prost" vergleichen. Es kommt dem Ausspruch am nächsten, aber es hat eben nicht die exakte Bedeutung wie "Kipp es!" auf dem deutschen Oktoberfest.
Auch bei anderen Vergleichen schwingt bei ** Dies bedeutet so viel wie** immer ein kleiner Unterschied mit. **So viel ich weiß** impliziert Unsicherheit in meiner Äußerung. Zum Beispiel: "So viel ich weiß, kommt Frau XY heute nicht zur Arbeit, weil ihr kleiner Sohn krank ist." Hier bedeutet **so viel**, dass ich meine zu wissen, warum Frau XY nicht zur Arbeit kommt, aber ich bin nicht 100% sicher.

Comment: Es würde die Lesbarkeit deines Posts verbessert, wenn du Absätze verwenden würdest. Für einen Absatz einfach eine leere Zeile, schon sind (und bleiben) die Absätze getrennt.